# What is the tetrachoric correlation coefficient?

Tags: correlation

I can calculate the tetrachoric and polycoric correlation coefficients by software, but i don't know What is the tetrachoric or polycoric coefficient furmula.

Comment: You could look at the code that's used to calculate it, by looking, for example, at the source of the polycor package in R - http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/polycor/R/ or similar in Stata.   I would be surprised if it were straightforward.

Comment: different packages use different algorithms to generate these now - so you will get different correlations using say R and Mplus

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3086/differences-between-tetrachoric-and-pearson-correlation