# What is Polychoric Correlation Coefficient intuitively?

Tags: correlation, factor-analysis, ordinal-data

There is clear meaning of *Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient*:

> it is cosine of angle between two vectors based on variables.

Also there are [12 other ways](http://mres.gmu.edu/readings/PSYC557/Rodgers_Nicewander_13ways_look_at_correlation.pdf) to clearify the meaning of *Pearson correlation*.

Is there any similar for *Polychoric correlation coefficient*? Besides just "correlation between two ordinal variables" and without complicated formulas.

Comment: Check Chi's answer to this question for a start: Differences between tetrachoric and Pearson correlation and http://john-uebersax.com/stat/tetra.htm

Comment: @user20650 I already have studied this link before. It is a good paper, but not complete and mainly aimed at _Tetrachoric_. I think there should be some textbooks with better description.

Comment: The referenced answer is presumably @chl's here: [Differences between tetrachoric and Pearson correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3135/7290).

Comment: Polychoric correlation is an _inferred Pearson correlation_. It is not correlation between _ordinal_ variables, it is correlation between "underlying" continuous variables whereof the ordinal variables are seen as the result of binning. When there is only 2 levels in the ordinal variables, it is called [tetrachoric](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/186026/3277) correlation.

Answer (score 2):

I found [Kolenikov and Angeles "The Use of Discrete Data in Principal Component Analysis" working paper](http://www.cpc.unc.edu/measure/publications/wp-04-85) to be helpful (published version [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1475-4991.2008.00309.x/abstract) if you have access). Slides [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150122003449/http://www.unc.edu/~skolenik/talks/Gustavo-Stas-PCA-generic.pdf) as well.

To quote the authors (from the help-file for their `polychoric` Stata command):

> The polychoric correlation of two ordinal variables is derived as
>   follows.  Suppose each of the ordinal variables was obtained by
>   categorizing a normally distributed underlying variable, and those two
>   unobserved variables follow a bivariate normal distribution. Then the
>   (maximum likelihood) estimate of that correlation is the polychoric
>   correlation.

Comment: It looks like it is good source. (Nevertheless, _Principal Component Analysis_ and _Factor Analysis_ are different things; and this is not a textbook.)

Comment: I managed to overlook that part somehow. Sorry!

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov: Seems like link is dead. Any chance you have a newer one?

Comment: @gary Found the file using Wayback Machine and edited the link.

Comment: Could you possibly add a brief summary for the answer to be self-contained?

Comment: @Tim Let me know if that's better.